# Connect to redis cluster deployed with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster

I've written a yaml file which deploy a redis cluster. The file content is

```
# ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster
data:
  update-node.sh: |
    #!/bin/sh
    REDIS_NODES="/data/nodes.conf"
    sed -i -e "/myself/ s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/${POD_IP}/" ${REDIS_NODES}
    exec "$@"
  redis.conf: |
    cluster-enabled yes
    cluster-require-full-coverage no
    cluster-node-timeout 15000
    cluster-config-file /data/nodes.conf
    cluster-migration-barrier 1
    appendonly yes
    protected-mode no
    requirepass az873J1DPdIc
    tcp-keepalive 0
    save 900 1
    save 300 10
    save 60 10000
---
#Secret
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: ewoJImF....
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: iranlms-key
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
---
#StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: redis-cluster
  replicas: 15
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: redis-data-pvc
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: local-path
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-cluster
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-cluster
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
                operator: In
                values:
                - redis1
                - redis2
                - redis3
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: iranlms-key
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: registry.iranlms.ir/repository/docker/redis:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        command: ["/conf/update-node.sh", "redis-server", "/conf/redis.conf"]
        env:
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: conf
          mountPath: /conf
          readOnly: false
        - name: redis-data-pvc
          mountPath: /data
          readOnly: false
      volumes:
      - name: conf
        configMap:
          name: redis-cluster
          defaultMode: 0755
---
#Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - 10.212.183.22
  - 10.212.183.23
  - 10.212.183.24
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
    name: client
  selector:
    app: redis-cluster
```

After applying the yaml file to the cluster, I also run some code to create the cluster. Now I want to connect to one of these redis instances with python. I use `pyredis` library. when I connect to the node I get this error

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis-cluster-0.redis-cluster:6379. Name or service not known.
```

I think the cluster instance is giving python client another node address to do the command but it gives a name which is not accssible outside the cluster. Should I forcefully need to have some /etc/hosts entry on all machines which the clients want to run?

### Update

I want to connect to this cluster from outside the cluster using the service I wrote in the config file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - 10.212.183.22
  - 10.212.183.23
  - 10.212.183.24
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
    name: client
  selector:
    app: redis-cluster
```

So on my laptop which has access to one of thoese ExternalIPS, I use this python code:

```
import redis
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='10.212.183.22', port=6379, db=0, password='az873J1DPdIc')
r.set("hello", "world")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/emadhelmi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 2238, in set
    return self.execute_command("SET", *pieces, **options)
  File "/home/emadhelmi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1258, in execute_command
    return conn.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "/home/emadhelmi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
    return do()
  File "/home/emadhelmi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1259, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._send_command_parse_response(
  File "/home/emadhelmi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1235, in _send_command_parse_response
    return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
  File "/home/emadhelmi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1275, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "/home/emadhelmi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 827, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MOVED 866 10.244.2.36:6379
```

### Update 2

Also when I connect to redis with python cluster mode, It hangs on the command and doesn't do anything(It does not return to the command line):

```
>>> r = redis.RedisCluster(host='10.212.183.22', port=6379, password='az873J1DPdIc')
```

### Update 3

I connected to the redis cluster using the `redis-cli` tool, on my laptop:

```
➜  ~ redis-cli -h 10.212.183.22 -p 6379 -a az873J1DPdIc -c
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
10.212.183.22:6379>
```

Then I try to set a key in the cluster:

```
10.212.183.22:6379> set hello world
-> Redirected to slot [866] located at 10.244.2.36:6379
Could not connect to Redis at 10.244.2.36:6379: Connection timed out
```

Comment: are you passing serice address as host in pyredis or POD name ? also you redis cluster is in cluster pattern right ? not single node, are you using the sentinel for cluster communication ?

Comment: @HarshManvar First, I used sentinel, I got the same error. As I read, I think sentinel does not proxy my request and it just give me(pyredis) the instance name to connect. So I think it is correct for Sentinel to give me the error. so I removed sentinel. I pass one of the nodes (VM) IP address which is accessible from outside the kubernetes cluster (the VM IP). And yes, I use these redis instances as the cluster pattern

Comment: you are giving node ip for connection to your code to service name directly for internal communication ?

Comment: @EmadHelmi where do you run python client? Is it kubernetes pod inside the same k8s cluster or an external to the cluster python client? Please add that info to the question.

Comment: @EmadHelmi please share the python code you use and its image so it will be possible to reproduce the issue

Comment: @rok I've added some more details in addition to the python code I use.

Comment: @HarshManvar I give it the IP, I've updated my question

Comment: thanks for sharing the detais you can access the IP of node but the port you are trying is not accessible maybe directly, you have to use the nodeport if want to access Redis with the node IP. if you are getting connected successfully there could be issue of you are hitting the read only node trying to set value there.

Comment: @HarshManvar I Have telnet to the IP and port from my laptop. So I think it is not the problem with the node IP,Port connectivity. I also run a `redis-cli` cluster mode. I put the details in the question.